# Trouble Understanding the Statement of a Theorem in Hatcher's Book

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. We write $f:(X,A)\to (Y, B)$ as a shorthand for writing $f:X\to Y$ and $f(A)\subseteq B$.

Now Proposition 2.19 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology reads:

> If two maps $f(X, A)\to (Y, B)$ are homotopic through maps of pairs $(X, A)\to (Y, B)$, then $f_*=g_*:H_n(X, A)\to H_n(Y, B)$.

I do not understand what is meant by *... homotopic through maps of pairs (X, A)\to (Y, B) ...*

Can somebody please write out the formal definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a map $f_t: X \times I \to Y$ such that $f_0 = f$, $f_1 = g$, and $f_t (A \times I )\subset B$. Conceptually "the image of $A$ is always inside $B$."